# Matrix reduction in Computational Topology: An Introduction

Tags: algebraic-topology, computational-mathematics

I'm working on learning Persistent Homology from "Computational Topology: An Introduction" by Herbert Edelsbrunner and John L. Harer.  In section VII.1,  Persistant Homology, they start with a monotonic function $f:K\to \mathbb R$ (monotonic in the sense that if $\sigma _i$ is a face of $\sigma _j$, then $f(\sigma _i)\le f(\sigma _j)$).

Using this function, they then reorder the simplices of $K$,  putting them all together from every level as $\sigma _1$ to $\sigma _n$  by the rule $i<j$ if $f(\sigma _i)<f(\sigma _J)$ or if $\sigma _i$ is a face of $\sigma _j$

They then define an $n$ by $n$  0-1 matrix $\partial$ by $\partial [i,j]=1$ if $\sigma _i$ is a codomension 1 face of $\sigma _j$

This puts the rows and columns as the simplicies and the boundary of a simplex is recorded in its column. They claim then to have an algorithm to reduce $\partial$ to another 0-1 matrix $R$.  They do this with a function $low(j)$ which is defined on nonzero columns $j$ as the lowest row that there exists a 1, and is undefined on 0 columns. I have two questions on this process.  First, the algorithm:

$$R=\partial$$
$$\text {for } j=1 \text { to } m \text { do}$$
$$\text { while there exists }j_0 <j\text { with }low(j_0)=low(j)\text { do}$$
$$\text {add column }j_o \text { to column }j $$
$$\text {endwhile}$$
$$\text {endfor}$$
First question that popped up:  How does this end up with a 0-1 matrix, if we are adding two columns with 1's in the same row?  My professor suggested they probably meant addition mod 2,  but I thought I'd check to see if anyone knows for certain.

Next,  they say that in matrix notation, the algorithm computes the reduced matrix as $R=\partial \cdot V$.  I'm not sure what $V$ is here,  or how that claim is made.  The only thing about it is a bit later where they say "the $j$-th column of $V$ encodes the columns in $\partial$ that add up to give the $j$-th column in $R$.  If anyone can clarify that, I'd appreciate it.